# "[WinError 5] Access is denied" error when trying to install numpy + mkl wheel

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I'm very new to coding, and just recently picked up Python to do some basic data analysis. I aim to use the sklearn module but found out that I need to install the numpy + mkl module prior to scipy. However, I got the error above when installing the numpy + mkl wheel. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: ...which error?

Comment: Do you use Windows? what error do you get? copy - paste it to your original post

Comment: How do you tried to download the module ? With pip ? If it's with pip then try to run the command in an administrator terminal

Comment: Yes, I used Windows. I did download the wheel, and did pip install file_name.whl but when I ran it on Shell it gives me the Access is denied error

Comment: Post the entire error on your post. Did you try my solution ?